# Maintaining name servers when redelegating the main domain

Tags: domain-name-system, vps

Just wanting to make sure I don't seriously bugger something up here, I'm 70% sure I'm doing the right thing. We have 2 hosting accounts, one is shared hosting, one is a VPS.

We are just about ready to cancel our shared account as we have moved all our sites over to the VPS. My only concern is the name servers, do the A records for the name servers have to be hosted somewhere other than the server its-self?

Our name servers are ns1.example.com.au and ns2.example.com.au - so we have the a records for these pointing to the correct IP addresses - BUT our domain example.com.au is pointed at the share host's name servers, if we point it to our name servers (ns1.example.com.au) will everything continue to work?

I've created the a records on the vps so it should receive it fine..

If someone could clarify this for me that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

> do the A records for the name servers have to be hosted somewhere other than the server its-
>   self?

No, they do not HAVE to be hosted somewhere else if you mean provider.

I you mean VPS - well, regulations say you need 2 DNS servers in independent networks and hardware and that has a good reason.

> BUT our domain example.com.au is pointed at the share host's name servers, if we point it
>   to  our name servers (ns1.example.com.au) will everything continue to
>   work?

Depends on whether you make it work or not as administrator.
Why you even bother putting the DNS On the same machine? I keep them on an independent service and am happy with that for years now.